# Problem with the pipeline request. System just drops out and doesn't proceed

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a method that is a custom middleware. This was copied exactly from the last solution with no changes.

```
using JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION.API.SessionMiddleware.Interfaces;
using JobsLedger.INTERFACES;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION.API.SessionMiddleware
{
    public class ConfigureSessionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ConfigureSessionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IUserSession userSession, ISessionServices sessionServices)
        {
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
            }

            if (userSession == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userSession));
            }

            if (sessionServices == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sessionServices));
            }

            if (httpContext.User.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated))
            {
                if (httpContext.Session.GetString("connectionString") == null) // Session needs to be set..
                {
                    userSession.UserId = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "userId")?.Value;
                    userSession.ConnectionString = sessionServices.ConnectionStringFromUserId(userSession.UserId);
                    httpContext.Session.SetString("userId", userSession.UserId);
                    httpContext.Session.SetString("connectionString", userSession.ConnectionString);
                }
                else  //  Session set so all we need to is to build userSession for data access..
                {
                    userSession.UserId = httpContext.Session.GetString("userId");
                    userSession.ConnectionString = httpContext.Session.GetString("connectionString");
                }
            }

            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

You will note that the bottom or last line has `await _next.Invoke(httpContext).ConfigureAwait(false);` which should call the next middleware. It doent. Sends me straight back to localhost on the browser. I suspect its suppose to process the request but it just jumps out of the pipeline and I have no idea.

Why is it dumping me out?

How can I debug it?

Can I see the next item that is suppose to come in the pipeline? (even if its not coming up).

UPDATE

I have a former solution that I refactored the current one from. I got this running in 3.1 and checked among other things the request and compared it to the current solutions httpcontext request. Here it is - only difference is the new or refacted solution has https (top one is current one that is jumping out of the request pipeline. Would this make a difference? Would it be that it cant find a controller.

[image]

Here is the controller I am trying to reach.

```
using JobsLedger.API.ViewModels.Auth;
using JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION;
using JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JobsLedger.API.Controllers.Authorisation {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class JwtController : Controller {
        #region Variables
        private readonly IUserAuthorisationServices _tokenService;
        private readonly IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> jwtOptions;
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings;
        #endregion

        public JwtController(IUserAuthorisationServices tokenService,
            IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> jwtOptions,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
            if (loggerFactory is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));

            _tokenService = tokenService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenService));

            jwtOptions = jwtOptions ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jwtOptions));
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<JwtController>();
            _serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            };
            //loggingRepository = _errorRepository;
            //ThrowIfInvalidOptions(this.jwtOptions);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromBody] LoginViewModel model) 
        { 
            if (model is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));

            var userContext = _tokenService.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password);

            if (userContext.Principal == null) {
                logger.LogInformation($"Invalid username ({model.Email}) or password ({model.Password})");
                return BadRequest("Invalid credentials");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a feeling you've dependency injected in the wrong place. You need to inject your dependencies in the constructor and then just have HttpContext on InvokeAsync. So it's probably throwing an exception when the dependency is null.

```
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
private readonly IUserSession _userSession;
private readonly ISessionServices _sessionServices;

public ConfigureSessionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IUserSession userSession, ISessionServices sessionServices)
{
    _next = next;
    _userSession = userSession;
    _sessionServices = sessionServices;
}

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    //rest of your code

}
```

If you're getting a 500 error, then you could put something like this at the start of Configure in Startup.cs which will should tell you the error in development.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(options =>
{
   options.Run(async context =>
   {
      var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
      if (ex?.Error != null)
      {
         Debugger.Break();
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.. not sure this is correct... in the initial pass it checks for id doesnt find one and jumps past the connectionstring section.. problem is that it hits that next statement and jumps out of the pipeline. Had an earlier version i did which is identical (as well as the configure method in startup - no changes) and that will jump straight to the JWT controller. The current one jumps out.

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest other than using a breakpoint and maybe a try catch in your invoke. You could also double check your adding the same stuff in ConfigureServices as your other project.

Comment: Its weird as the ConfigureServices is identical.. I did break but it just jumps straight to the browser - could it be that it just isnt finding the controller and therefore stops?

Comment: The response was: POST https://localhost:44301/api/jwt 500
services/auth/auth-service.AuthService.login @ auth-service.ts:52
public/components/login/login.Login.submitLogin @ login.ts:33
evaluate @ aurelia-binding.js:1517
callSource @ aurelia-binding.js:5232
handleEvent @ aurelia-binding.js:5241
handleDelegatedEvent @ aurelia-binding.js:3306
auth-service.ts:59 STATUS:  500 
auth-service.ts:96 catch error SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

Comment: Looks like you're getting an internal server error, so I've edited my answer which should let you inspect the error on development.

Comment: This addition to Configure pointed me in the right direction.. it really helped.  I have problems with DI on one of my classes.